# Akka HTTP ambiguous implicit conversion

Tags: scala, rest, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm cutting my teeth on Akka HTTP by working this [example](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/akka-http-microservice). For the purposes of learning, I converted it to a Maven project. However, I'm getting compilation errors as follows using Akka v2.3.12 and Akka Stream v1.0. The POST DSL fails with similar errors that I'm not posting for brevity. How can I get the example to run?

```
pathPrefix("ip") {
(get & path(Segment)) { ip =>
  complete {
    fetchIpInfo(ip).map[ToResponseMarshallable] {
      case Right(ipInfo) => ipInfo
      case Left(errorMessage) => BadRequest -> errorMessage
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
[ERROR]  found   : akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive[(String,)]
[ERROR]  required: ?{def apply: ?}
[ERROR] Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
[ERROR]  both method addDirectiveApply in object Directive of type [L](directive: akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive[L])(implicit hac: akka.http.scaladsl.server.util.ApplyConverter[L])hac.In => akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
[ERROR]  and method fromDirective in object ConjunctionMagnet of type [L, R](other: akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive[R])(implicit join: akka.http.scaladsl.server.util.TupleOps.Join[L,R])akka.http.scaladsl.server.ConjunctionMagnet[L]{type Out = akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive[join.Out]}
[ERROR]  are possible conversion functions from akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive[(String,)] to ?{def apply: ?}
[ERROR]         (get & path(Segment)) { ip =>
```

---

```
error: akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive[(String,)] does not take parameters
[ERROR]         (get & path(Segment)) { ip =>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is due to the deep `implicit` chain that Spray (and hence akka-http) uses so getting the imports right is crucial. Very few examples show the imports and those that do, use old libraries.

Comment: Three years later and I get a similar one, this time from a plain `String` to `?{def apply: ?}`. It happens on `storeFileUpload("fieldName", ...)`. When I replace `storeFileUpload` with its definition (simple beta reduction), it works! Seems like Scala implements λ-Calculus modulo implicit conversion!! As `storeFileUpload` is marked as `ApiMightChange` I just gave up. Wish there was an `Applicative` type class in Scala. Disclaimer: I love Scala, still more than Haskell. But implicit conversion is painful when used on broad types like `String`!

Comment: @NaderGhanbari what do you mean you gave up?

Comment: I couldn't make it compile so I literally copy pasted the body of `storeFileUpload` and put it in my own trait and it works.